# After I have installed VirtualBox in Redhat, I cannot run an Ubuntu OS inside the VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=vbox&f=1

^This is the link of the website I followed for the installation of the VirtualBox (Part 1 specifically)

I am using a Windows 10 OS(Host), on Windows 10 I am running Redhat on Workstation Pro 15, and in the Redhat I have install VirtualBox.
I have tried running the VirtualBox, adding an iso file to the storage adapter settings. I have also tried doing it on a fresh Redhat OS but there is still the same error. Thanks in Advance

Below is the error prompt

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Lubuntu.

The device helper structure version has changed.

If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox. (VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: My guess is that this has nothing to do with the OS (Lubuntu) you are trying to install in Virtualbox. Can you launch any other VMs? This may not be the best forum for your question.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your error message but the error messages as a text.

Comment: Hmmm. Seems a VirtualBox (host) error, not a Lubuntu (guest) error. I would suggest trying VirtualBox support.

Comment: I have tried using 32 bit OS but still failed. Currently I only tried different types of ubuntu OS. P.S. I am new to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

## This might not be possible.

According to [this forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=86922),  VirtualBox does not support nested virtualization:

> Nested virtualization currently is not supported, and we in general don't provide any estimates or road map (planning) to the public.

What you *can* try is disabling hardware virtualization in the guest OS's VirtualBox and then running a 32-bit guest in the guest. This will probably be about as fast as a dead turtle.

Some other virtualization technologies do support nested virtualization, though. For example, [KVM does](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM#Nested_virtualization).